# Remove a certain string from a PHP input text field before saving it to MySQL database

Tags: php, html

**What I want to achieve:** I want to use a simple PHP form to send data to a MySQL database. However, when the input contains a certain string, I want to remove it before it is saved in the MySQL database.

> Example: input is 'https://www.google.com', but I want to remove the
>   'https://' part, so only 'www.google.com' is saved in the database.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php but for URLs maybe http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_replace()` to remove the parts you don't want:

```
$input = 'https://www.google.com';
$replaced = str_replace('https://', '', $input);

echo $replaced;
```

If you want to replace multiple values in one pass, you also do that (this will remove `http://`, `https://` and `ftp://`):

```
$unwanted  = array("http://", "https://", "ftp://");
$replace   = array("", "", "");

$replaced = str_replace($unwanted, $replace, $input);
```

See: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php